# Update record in Source when it change in CRM

Tags: c#, mysql, plugins, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011

Currently we have two methods to insert/update records in to CRM (2011 on premise).

1. One is from till system ERP using SSIS and CRM web service (C#). This integration, happens every hour. It integrates data from mySQL to CRM using web service.
2. Second method is when Contact clicks on 'Update your profile' link in the email communication.

Issue: Lets say Contact changes his/her phone number, using the link in the email. Now we have correct updated telephone number in CRM. However, when the hourly integration runs, it will update this phone number (as it will differ from the one in source).

**Question: How can I use CRM trigger to fire off some C# code? I would like to update the source, the moment the target record gets updated by Contact. I have no control over the PHP script that updates record in CRM. Is there any way to update record in external mySQL table when record gets modified in CRM? We are expecting no more then 15 record per week.**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a CRM plugin that use C# on updating the entity in CRM.

please refer to this link : [Sample: Basic plug-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx)